# Check whether table gets updated every five minutes

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am checking whether a table in Google Big Query gets updated every 5 minutes. We have a DateTime field in the table that gets a record for every 5 minutes starting from a specified time. I have to get the starting time (last record) of the table and check whether we have a record for the last 10 minutes from the current DateTime. In the result table, for each machine, I should have a "yes" or "no" based on whether table gets updated every 5 mins.

Current Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [Poll_20160505]
WHERE MachineName = 'P130'
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
```

Current output:

```
MachineName DateTime
P130        2016-07-07 15:54:13.407
P130        2016-07-07 15:49:13.438
P130        2016-07-07 15:44:13.437
P130        2016-07-07 15:39:13.426
P130        2016-07-07 15:34:13.419
.
.
P130        2016-07-07 00:09:13.037
P130        2016-07-07 00:04:13.005
```

Expected Output:

```
MachineName DateTime
P130        Yes
```

Edit:

I should have "yes" if the difference between current timestamp and the latest timestamp in the table is greater than 8 minutes (bcz table gets updated every 5 mins, giving a buffer of 3 mins).

From the above table, i have to find the difference between current timestamp and the timestamp of the first record (2016-07-07 15:54:13.407), if it is greater than 8 mins, then i should have a "no", else i should have "yes".

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: @DanBracuk: I have added an edit. I am not able to find the difference between two timestamps which are stored as strings.

Comment: criteria for yes vs. no is not clear  - you said - `I should have a "yes" or "no" based on whether table gets updated every 5 mins` - Is it for some last N minutes or since very first record? so even one 5 min gap should produce `no`?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: I will have a "yes" if all the records are within the 7 minutes (buffer of 2 minutes) difference. If we dont get a new record every 7 minutes, then I should have "no"

Comment: not totaly clear yet. i still can read it in many different ways. can you give an example of two/three consequitive records that would produce `yes` vs. another example of two/three that would produce `no` and comment why

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant: I have edited the question.

Comment: I got the answer - I did this (TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(Current_TimeStamp) - TIMESTAMP_TO_USEC(DateTime))/(1000000*60)

Comment: i just posted my answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope, it is as simple as below

```
SELECT 
  MachineName, 
  CASE 
    WHEN TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(recentDateTime) < 8 * 60 THEN "Yes" 
    ELSE "No"
  END AS Healthy
FROM (
  SELECT MachineName, MAX(DateTime) AS recentDateTime 
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY MachineName
)
```